# PHP script can't access blog site for rss because they share domain name

Tags: domain

I have a php script sitting on a webserver. The domain for the server we'll say is 'www.example.com'. We also have a blog. This blog sits on a totally different server, but it accessed via 'www.example.com/blog'. Because these two sites share a domain name, my server looks internally for the feed my script is trying to access. How can I make the server look outside the localhost?

Comment: How did you manage to do that?

Comment: I'm not really sure how it works to be honest. The blog is hosted by Compendium, a large commercial blog company. Somehow they set things up so that the /blog on the domain goes to their host blog.

Comment: If you can't describe how this is set up, then perhaps you should share the exact name of the site so that the rest of us can try to figure it out. It will be very close to impossible to give a good answer to the question otherwise.

Comment: I would gather your web server is setup using a Proxy module or something.   As for how you access the blog, it completely depends on how you are accessing the remote system.  If you are using CURL under PHP, I would bet you can provide the IP of the blog server, and the hostname, in the HTTP request that you send.

Comment: After spending a lot of time digging I found it is using a proxy. How would I make the server route this request through the proxy?

Comment: it's actually a 'reverse proxy' I'm being told.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So, the answer it turns out wasn't so much a server issue as a php issue. I had to route the php call through Compendium's reverse proxy. It was done like this:

```
$aContext = array('http'=>array('proxy'=>'tcp://client-proxy.compendiumblog.com:80','request_fulluri'=>true));
$url = "http://www.example.com/blog";
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$xml = file_get_contents($url,FALSE,$cxContext);
$xmldoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

Comment: It does, and I will. I just have to wait a day. My apologies for posting something that wound up not being a server issue. I really thought it was going to be related to Internal DNS or something.